# Slim framework array is not encoding in JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json, slim

I have an array I'm encoding in JSON using withJson() but it is throwing slim application error.
Below is my code and array value:

```
            $db = Db::get_instance();
            $stmt = $db->query($sql);
            if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
            {
                $dataList = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                //print_r($dataList);die;
            }
            $data = array();
            foreach($dataList as $row)
            { //print_r($row);
                $id = '';
                $name = '';
                foreach($row as $key=>$value)
            {
                if($key == 'id') $id = $value;
                if($key == 'countname') $countname = trim($value);
                if($key == 'city') $city = trim($value);
                if($key == 'region') $region = trim($value);
                if($key == 'type')
                { 
                    if($value == 'country') $name="$countname ($value)";
                    if($value == 'state') $name = "$region, $countryname ($value)";
                    if($value == 'city') $name="$city,$region,$countname ($value)";
                }
                //$name = str_replace(',',' ',$name);
                $temp['id'] = $id;
                $temp['name'] = $name;
            }
            $data[] = $temp;
        }print_r($data);die;
        return $response->withJson($data,200);
```

***Please note*** there are some special characters in my array:[7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4634
            [name] => Saint-g�rard,,Belgium (city)
        )

My array is below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 65
            [name] => Ura Vajgurore,,Albania (city)
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2024
            [name] => Birregurra,,Australia (city)
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2703
            [name] => Kallangur,,Australia (city)
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 985
            [name] => Gurnitz,,Austria (city)
        )
)
```

Comment: What error is displayed?

Comment: You mention that a `slim application error` is thrown but haven't added it to the question. Are you able to provide the error message as that might narrow down the problem.

Comment: error_reporting (E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);                                                                                   Even this code is not showing any error.

Comment: remove `print_r($data);die;`

Comment: that is commented in code. here it is uncommented just to show array values and format

Comment: where do you get ` $response` from?

Comment: public function getLocations(Request $request, Response $response, $args)

Comment: can you `var_dump($response->withJson($data,200)); die();`

Comment: still throwing slim application error. no luck

Comment: `$data = array('name' => 'Bob', 'age' => 40);
$newResponse = $oldResponse->withJson($data);`

can you try this and see if it gives the same error, if not there is something wrong with your array

Comment: please note there are some special characters in my array:[7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4634
            [name] => Saint-g�rard,,Belgium (city)
        )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned that there were special characters in my `array` data:
example:

```
 [7] => Array
            (
                [id] => 4634
                [name] => Saint-gÚrard,,Belgium (city)
            )
```

you have to reset constant name after DB connection establishment:

```
$db = Db::get_instance();
$db->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8';");
```

Hope this would work for you.